# how to display json content and if field is empty then dont display

Tags: jquery, json

I need to check if json fields are empty if not empty display content what I have doesn't seem to work

```
<script  src="http://mywebsite.com/benefits/?json=get_recent_posts&callback=listBenefits" > </script>

<script>

    function listBenefits(data) {

    $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {

     if ( val.length !== 0 ) {
     output += '<li>' +  val.custom_fields.extra_content_extra_content_second_value +  "</li>"; 
        }

    if (val.length !== 0 ) {
         output += '<li>' +  val.custom_fields.extra_content_extra_content_third_value +  "</li>";
    }

    });

    }
</script>
```

json url output

```
  object {5}
    status :    ok
    count : 10
    count_total : 10
    pages : 1
    posts [10]

        custom_fields

            extra_content_extra_content_third_value
```

I have also tried this

```
if (jQuery.isEmptyObject (val.custom_fields.extra_content_extra_content_third_value)) {
output += '<li>' +  val.custom_fields.extra_content_extra_content_third_value +  "</li>";
}
```

this is the original code, I just need the list not to display if there is no value

```
output += '<li>' +  val.custom_fields.extra_content_extra_content_third_value +  "</li>";
```

Comment: What is `val` ? What is expected result of second `if` ?

Comment: have you tried 'val != null' instead of 'val.length !== 0'?

Comment: Before you check `val`, you have to check `data.posts` first. I would suggest `console.log( data )` just to confirm you have the right data.

Comment: Why do two `if` statements with the same test?

Comment: val is the value coming from json file

Comment: @ PeterKA  I have data displaying form the json file, but if the field is empty then I just have the empty <li>

Comment: `output` not appear defined outside of `$.each()` ? Is `output` appended to document ? Can include `json` `data` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Check out my answer below. I am guessing you have an array of objects ... so to avoid confusion may be `function(index, val)` is better.

Comment: I am using the wordpress json api plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: Instead, I would try this sneaky one liner after your code:

```js
$('li').each(function(){if ($(this).html().length == 0) $(this).remove()});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hey</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>get off my cloud</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need the (key, val)  this is the value from json file

Comment: I am getting data from the json file,  I just need to not display the list if there is no data to display

Comment: At the bottom just add an empty line remover: $('li').map(if $(this).html().length == 0 return $(this)).remove();

Comment: sorry i forgot to add function, add this after your code: $('li').each(function(){if ($(this).html().length == 0) $(this).remove()});

Comment: this works $('li').each(function(){if ($(this).html().length === 0) $(this).remove();});

Comment: one more thing Dreamweaver is telling me   Expected '{' instead saw '$'

Comment: you may have to surround $(this).remove(); in squigglies:    {$(this).remove();}

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
//don't forget to initialize output variable
var output = '';

//check if data is defined and that it has posts key
if( data && data.posts ) {
    $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {
        //check if the loooooooong key has some data -- string
        if( val.custom_fields.extra_content_extra_content_second_value.trim().length ) {
            //your code here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: still displays the list tags

Comment: Please provide a sample portion of the data.

Comment: I was really hoping to see the data -- just a sample of it, not the code. A look at the structure and a sample record you'd like skipped would be helpful.